# Ruby unit test (gets.chomp)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, refactoring

I have ruby class:

```
class Sample
  def main
    zipcode = gets.chomp

    if correct_length?(zipcode)
    end

  end

  def correct_length?(string)
    true if string.size == 5
  end
end

instance = Sample.new
instance.main
```

and test for it:

```
require_relative 'sample'
require 'test/unit'

class TestSample < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_correct_length?
    zipcode = '10234'
    assert_equal(true, Sample.new.correct_length?(zipcode))
  end
end
```

I want to test just **correct_length?** method. When I run the test I must enter some characters before tests start. How should I rewrite this example to test just a method (not running **gets.chomp**)

Comment: Change your method name to `_main`, to avoid clash may be in future with the top level `self`.

Comment: Just for my understanding: when you run the test you have to insert any zipcode first? If so: move the executing part into another ruby file which you do not require during your tests. If i am not mistaken they are executed during require_relative - then just write the tests as you already are doing

Comment: @TobiasSchoknecht I don't want to split file with method. Falsetru anwser is correct.

Comment: @ArupRakshit could you explain me why should I change main into _main? I'm new in Ruby language.

Comment: Well, if spliting is not an option, then the answer from falsetru probably has the best and easiest solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround the part that call `main` with `if __FILE__ == $0 ... end`; If you run test, that part will not executed while the part is executed if the script is executed as an entry point.

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  instance = Sample.new
  instance.main
end
```